# More effective way to open and close modals with js

Tags: javascript, html, dom, dom-events

I'm still learning js, I'd like to find a way to reduce all the code I put below, I want to open different modals and close them in html.

In the Open modal section as you can see I made a function per modal where the "varEdit-button" is the ID I assigned to each button to open them and the "var-modal" ID is the one I assigned to each different modal container.

In the Close modal section the "close-varModal" is the ID I assigned to each close container and the "var-modal" again is the ID for each modal container.

I'd like to reduce the code with a for loop or maybe another property of js.

For example, I tried to close all the modals just by assigning the same class `.close` to all the close containers but only the first modal I opened could close and if someone knows why that happens with this language I'd appreciate it!

```
//OPEN MODALS
document.getElementById('imageEdit-button').addEventListener('click',
    function (){
    document.querySelector('#pic-modal').style.display = 'flex';
    });

document.getElementById('curpEdit-button').addEventListener('click',
    function (){
    document.querySelector('#curp-modal').style.display = 'flex';
    });

document.getElementById('phoneEdit-button').addEventListener('click',
    function (){
    document.querySelector('#phone-modal').style.display = 'flex';
    });

document.getElementById('addressEdit-button').addEventListener('click',
    function (){
    document.querySelector('#address-modal').style.display = 'flex';
    });



// CLOSE MODALS
document.querySelector('#close-picModal').addEventListener('click',
    function (){
    document.querySelector('#pic-modal').style.display = 'none';
    });

document.querySelector('#close-curpModal').addEventListener('click',
    function (){
    document.querySelector('#curp-modal').style.display = 'none';
    });

document.querySelector('#close-phoneModal').addEventListener('click',
    function (){
    document.querySelector('#phone-modal').style.display = 'none';
    })

document.querySelector('#close-addressModal').addEventListener('click',
    function (){
    document.querySelector('#address-modal').style.display = 'none';
    })
```

Comment: You can refer to this [article](https://medium.com/@GistCoding/simple-popup-modal-with-vanilla-javascript-a14515ec630b) and find working [code](https://codepen.io/kimpetersend1/pen/LajgaW)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One option is to give the open and close buttons an attribute, perhaps in the dataset, that specifies the ID or (unique) class of the element to open/close. For example:

```js
for (const button of document.querySelectorAll('button[data-target]')) {
  button.addEventListener('click', () => {
    const target = document.querySelector('#' + button.dataset.target);
    target.classList[button.matches('.close') ? 'add' : 'remove']('closed');
  });
}
```

```css
.closed {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<button data-target="imageEdit">open image edit</button>
<div id="imageEdit" class="closed">
  <h3>image edit</h3>
  <button class="close" data-target="imageEdit">close</button>
</div>
```

For additional sections, simply add more HTML, adjusting the `data-target`s as needed.

You could also tweak the logic so that a click on any of the buttons will toggle the current state of the target, if you wanted, simplifying the line inside the click listener to

```
target.classList.toggle('closed');
```